# Is including multiple data types in a field an anti-pattern?

Tags: design, e-commerce, anti-patterns

On Venmo's web app, you create a transaction by selecting a recipient and then filling out a field that includes a dollar amount and a description:

[image: Venmo payment field, with example text "$5.75 for ice cream!"]

Both the dollar amount and the description are mandatory, and they can only be entered in this field. If you just enter "8.00", for example, it's rejected--you have to use the format "[number] for [thing]".

This was confusing for me at first* since a dollar sign at the left of a field seems to indicate that it's a field for a numeric dollar amount. In fact, I don't think I've *ever* seen this done before, even on paper forms--all checks have separate fields for the transaction amount and the memo, for example. At the very least, this seems like bad accessibility, since some platforms may have different controls for numeric vs. text fields, and there's no good reason that I'm aware of to require users to enter a monetary amount as text.

Are there any valid reasons to create fields like this?

*On Venmo in particular, this is exacerbated by the unhelpful error message `A transaction must have a note, e.g., "Kale salad with beans, onions, mushrooms, berries, and seeds."`, which goes into details about someone's salad but fails to provide an example of correct input. But I'm wondering about this field format in general.

Comment: An input mask may make it better but definitely seems like a "style over function" decision.

Comment: That is a gross way to expect someone to fill in a form and the error message is completely unhelpful. That said, I can see what they're trying to do: they're trying to make the form conversational, which in turns gives the form a "friendly" feel. They've done it very, very poorly, but that's the particular technique that they're going for.

Comment: Select statement for a database is pretty big anti pattern.  A programming language.   If a field did not have mixed data there would be not need for parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this **PROBABLY is an anti pattern**. Please note the PROBABLY word, because anti-patterns are usually measured on client's side. But given the information you provided and with some experience on my back, I'd bet money this is like the definition of an anti pattern: something that looks like a great idea at first, but use demonstrates it's counter-productive or provides a bad experience to users (like in your case)

Let's look to a known example: **credit card numbers.** There are lot of studies about the proper UX of a string which **only has number and a known pattern** . Even on this site, you'll find lots of question about this, including whether to use a single input, use masked inputs, use 4 different inputs, auto tab and so on.

Now, your example: it has **2 extremely different** data types, with no clue on affordance and everything in the same field. Furthermore: if you don't comply with the mysterious UX, your input doesn't validate. And as you say, even on *validation error messages*, it's unclear what to do.

Now, compare both cases: one is way simpler, has a lot of studies about it and still represents a problem sometimes, including some anti patterns here and there. The other is complicated, with obfuscated data, unclear for the user and no clues on affordance, with botched validation messages. So.... what would you say about this? *(I know what would you say because you said it in your question, and you're 100% right, it's a rhetorical question)*

In short: as I said, **I don't have the client's side data to confirm this is an anti pattern** but... *If it looks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, we have at least to consider the possibility that we have a small aquatic bird of the family Anatidae on our hands.*

## EDIT:

On a second view, now I can see they can share this payment on Facebook... guess that's the explanation for the convoluted UX, but well... posting your financial movements on Facebook is weird to say the least. As a matter of fact, this is the weirdest part of this UX for me

Comment: Yeah, as Madalina Taina noted, the focus on the transaction description is probably there to fuel the sense of conversation--you can see in the screenshot that "Public" is the default privacy setting, and right below that form, there's a timeline of your friends' money exchanges . I have no idea why that necessitates entering it all in one field though, especially since the mobile app uses separate fields like everything else in the world.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a marketing strategy, they want to keep the transactions friendly and in this case the accent is on the action, not on the money.

They explain how to fill the input with the placeholder and I'm sure they have a solution to insert the sum separately in the database.

I don't find this wrong or counter-productive, so I don't think this is an anti-pattern.

Comment: "They explain how to fill the input with the placeholder" I disagree, I don't think the placeholder appropriately explains the field, it just gives you a single example of a valid input. You don't know, for example, that the word "for" is required. You don't know if you have to enter cents or not. Can you enter 50c or does it need to be $0.50?  I agree with your theory that this is an attempt to make the form "friendly" but I think they've done it poorly in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Putting multiple data types into a single field definitely does have issues, when storing and recovering from the database, one merged it'll be very problematic separating the data.

However I think they might be trying a natural language approach for this field.

e.g. http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/NaturalLanguageForm/

so while it might look like a single field, it might actually be a form

Answer (score 0):

It's not because it's mixed values, but because it's pretty unclear what that input field needs to be valid.

Instead of just showing that placeholder, it should have probably been designed as such:

[image: mockup]

This actually makes it very clear what to input, because it guides you through the process, instead of assuming users will know what to write.

Comment: That would definitely make it clearer what should go in the field, but wouldn't the form still be relatively non-accessible since it would be a `text` field instead of a `number` field e.g.? I found this on the desktop version of the site, but it still makes a difference for people who have onscreen keyboards or are using tablets.

Comment: Why would this not make it accessible? It could easily shift from numbers only keyboard to full blown keyboard?

Comment: How would it do that? Most phones e.g. use different keyboards for a field depending on whether it's an input for `text`, `number`, etc., but each field can only have one type (`textarea`, in this case).

Comment: That input field doesn't have to be an input field at all. I'm not too sure why you're concerned with the technical aspect, especially because this is mainly for UX. But because I code for work too... ill do it anyway...

That whole field can easily be a div, and inside of it, the gray areas could be input fields, the first one an input of number and the second an input of text...

Comment: I don't think they'd really be the same field then.

Comment: And why does it have to be?

Comment: Because that's what the question asks--I'm asking whether it's confusing to tell users to input multiple data types in the same field, not whether there's a better way. Using multiple fields of different types is great and sane and terrific, but it's not what Venmo e.g. is doing.

Comment: No matter what you do, you can do it in a non-confusing way if it is designed well: tech shouldn't limit your design in an ideal world. It might technically be two input fields, but to the user it will appear to be one input field.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it is the best pattern here but it is not an anti pattern.  If a field did not have mixed data there would be not need for parsers.

- query statement for a database (SQL)
- programming language
- Number of document management applications use a search syntax with
  multiple field types.  It is part of them CMIS specification.
- Many of the litigation support applications use that syntax
- Westlaw syntax is common
- [Jason](http://www.json.org/)
- [ODATA](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/)
- [LUCENE](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) (the leading search engine)

Comment: I guess that's true for a very broad definition of form field (i.e. one that considers an entire program a field), but here I'm thinking more specifically about fields on a traditional POST-type web form. All I could find on Westlaw syntax is a type of natural language search, which may be a good example of this pattern used intuitively.

Comment: Oh, so now we are limited to POST-type web form.   I am developer and I in not way consider it an anti pattern.  I am parsing user input for multiple data types and conditions in a FIELD all the time.  Language type query is part of the specification for CMIS (standard for CMS).  JSON syntax http://www.json.org/

Comment: Can you give an example of where you've had to extract two or more *expected* inputs from one data field?

Comment: "An AntiPattern is a literary form that describes a commonly occurring solution to a problem that generates decidedly negative consequences." Just because you *can* parse it doesn't mean you should. In any case where you have an expected number/pattern of inputs just make them distinct inputs.

Comment: @AndreDickson date range, a full text search,  "john & sally", "!john | sally", I do it all the time.   There is a big range of search applications that parse down a simple to complex query syntax is the norm.   Development has gotten away from a GUI UI - all my development I type.  You just cannot depict anything advanced in a one box does one thing.

Comment: It seems that for a search input this pattern would be fine. However, note that the expected input for a search field is a search term and not the phrases used to query the corpus. Also, date ranges are typically specified as multiple inputs. Date pickers are an established UI pattern of their own.

Comment: @DasBeasto  Negative consequence to you.  Really a programming language or a query an is an  AntiPattern?  Could you articulate the negative  decidedly negative consequences?   How would you you design this UI?  select ID, name, subject from document where name in (john) and domain in (com, net) and date between (1/1/2000, 1,1,2001) and text (houton w10 texas) order by date decs

Comment: @Paparazzi Either you're not understanding the question or you're being decidedly stubborn. **Nobody here is questioning whether a programming language is an antipattern because nobody here is associating an input field with a programming language**.

Comment: @DasBeasto Really I give 8 examples and I don't get it because a program language is one example.  Maybe you don't associate a field with more than one data type with a programming language but it is.  Syntax rules, validate syntax, parse, and then compile or interpret.   It is a simple language and it is programmed like a programming language.

Comment: @Paparazzi, I think the problem with your answer is that you're seeing the programming side of the question, and there's no doubt about it. But the question is about the USER experience, and most users won't know what looks common to you

Comment: @Devin Really - no doubt?  I write a document management application for a living.  That is our search UI.  That is the search UI of most of our competitors.  Our users like it.  When I tell the UX we need to define the language you know what the say - "you're seeing the programming side of the question".   Does not change the fact that it is a language and the language needs to be defined.   Not all UI/UX is wire frames.   You just don't get it, and there's is not doubt about it.  Was there any purpose to "there's no doubt about it" other than to be rude?

Comment: Maybe it's my bad English. What I meant is EXACTLY what you said, that *there's no doubt about it* when you say in programming this is OK and it works. Sorry if you understood something different

Comment: @Paparazzi To clarify, I'm talking about whether it's an antipattern for web forms that let users _submit content_. I'd assume that most users are aware that search forms are for finding, rather than creating, content, so there aren't really the same design expectations. Search that parses the user's query is very commonplace, but a Twitter client that parsed your posted tweets upon submission (beyond tagging and url shortening) would be more surprising.

Comment: @Paparazzi "Was there any purpose to "there's no doubt about it" other than to be rude?", yes the purpose was to agree with you without a doubt -_-

Comment: @MiloPrice Maybe web form submitt is what you are talking about now.  There are two question marks in your post.  Is including multiple data types in a field-an-anti-pattern? Are there any valid reasons to create fields like this? For me to take those a general questions is a valid and proper interpretation.  The first sentence of my answer "I don't think it is the best pattern here but it is not an anti pattern."    It is not an anti pattern.  It is a very established pattern.